# DropDownList Binding to ActionResult Create Method MVC 4 VS2012

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, html-select

I'm a brand new user here - but I've been searching for a couple of hours now to solve following problem:

I've got 2 Entities - Category and Item.
Each Item should belong to a Category - therefore I would like to have a DropDownList which shows all existing Categories when Creating a new Item.
So far my code shows the DropDownList with all the Categories, but when I select a Category and Submit the form (POST) the value for Category is always null.
This naturally causes ModelState.IsValid to be false, because Category isn't nullable.
How can I get the User-Selected-Value into my Create(POST) method?

```
I've got a Controller with following Methods to Create a new Item:

// GET Method
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.CategorySet, "Id", "CategoryName");
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Item item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      db.ItemSet.Add(item);
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

return View(item);
}

And this is the DropDownList in my View (Create.cshtml):
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.DropDownList("Category", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.Categories, "--Select Category--")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I ended up with a custom view model - that way I got it working...

For those of you who don't know what a custom view model is:
You create a new class which contains all the values you need to create your new object, in my example a class which contains a SelectList (property) of available Categories, an integer value (property) for SelectedCategoryId and the Item (property) you want to create.
In your cshtml file you add this class as @model ....CustomCreateItemModel and use it in your DropDownList

Answer (score 0):

If your Item has a CategoryId property:

```
public class Item
{
  public int CategoryId {get;set;]
}
```

You will need to name your `DropDownList` to `"CategoryId"` so that the `ModelBinder` will be able to bind the value correctly

Or use the strongly typed helper:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.CategoryId...)
```

Comment: yes I do have an int Id as Primary Key in both entities, but I still can't figure out how to get this thing running... I've tried to change the DropDownList, but then it's not even showing my Items anymore

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Armen.

I had the same issue with my dropdown list being populated OK from the database but the OrganisationID (in my case) not making it to the database when a new record was created (in my case only 0 was always captured) - until I just changed the name of the ViewBag to be identical to the value in the dropdown (i.e. both OrganisationID) - as you had helpfully pointed out - and now it works!

For what it's worth, for anyone else going through the frustration that "Desperate coder" and I went through when our naming wasn't consistent to enable binding, here's what I have used to get a dropdown list working (sorry - NOT using the Entity Framework, but the principle should still be clear and easy to adapt if you are using the EF):

But the key takeaway is identical naming to enable binding. Thanks again Armen!

**MODEL**

```
public class Organisation_Names
    {
        public DataSet GetOrg_Names()
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=XXXXXXXXX;User ID=XXXXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXXXXXXX");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetOrg_Names", cn);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
//
    // GET: /Services/Create
    **public ActionResult Create(Organisation_Names organisation_names)
    {
        DataSet ds = organisation_names.GetOrg_Names();
        ViewBag.OrganisationID = ds.Tables[0];
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.OrganisationID.Rows)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = @dr["OrganisationName"].ToString(), Value = @dr["OrganisationID"].ToString() });
        }
        ViewBag.OrganisationID = items;
        return View();
 }


 //
    // POST: /Services/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    **public ActionResult Create(CreateServiceModel createservicemodel, Organisation_Names organisation_names, FormCollection selection)
    {
DataSet ds = organisation_names.GetOrg_Names();
        if (ds == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.OrganisationID = ds.Tables[0];
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.OrganisationID.Rows)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = @dr["OrganisationName"].ToString(), Value = @dr["OrganisationID"] + 1.ToString() });
        }
        ViewBag.OrganisationID = items;**

if (this.IsCaptchaVerify("Answer was incorrect. Please try again."))
        {
            try
            {
int _records = createservicemodel.CreateService(createservicemodel.OrganisationID, createservicemodel.ServiceName, createservicemodel.ServiceDescription, createservicemodel.ServiceComments,   createservicemodel.ServiceIdentificationNumber, createservicemodel.CreatedBy, createservicemodel.NewServiceID);

                if (_records > 0)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Services");
                }
            }
            catch
            //else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cannot Create");
            }

        }
        {
            return View(createservicemodel);
        }


    }
```

**VIEW**

```
@model WS_TKC_MVC4.Models.CreateServiceModel
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers
@using WS_TKC_MVC4.Models
@{ViewBag.Title = "Service added by " ;} @User.Identity.Name


<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript">     </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>CreateServiceModel</legend>

<div class="editor-label">
    <p>Select Organisation</p>
</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("OrganisationID")
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrganisationID)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrganisationID)
    </div>
```

(Some more fields)

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MathCaptcha)
    </div>
    @Html.MathCaptcha("Refresh", "Type answer below", "Answer is a required field.")

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```